# KMM ошибки при сборке android приложения

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

build.gardle.kts:shared:

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
}

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    targetHierarchy.default()

    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    val ktorVersion = "1.5.0"
    val coroutinesVersion = "1.4.2-native-mt"
    val serializationVersion = "1.0.1"
    val sqlDelightVersion = "1.4.4"

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:${serializationVersion}")

                // HTTP
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:${ktorVersion}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:${ktorVersion}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:${ktorVersion}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:${ktorVersion}")

                // Coroutines
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:${coroutinesVersion}")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:coroutines-extensions:${sqlDelightVersion}")

                // DI
                implementation("org.kodein.di:kodein-di:7.1.0")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.sciencehub"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 27
    }
}
```

Я получаю ошибки:

> failed
> Download info
> Kotlin Multiplatform <-> Android Gradle Plugin compatibility issue: The applied Android Gradle Plugin version (8.3.0-alpha11) is higher than the maximum known to the Kotlin Gradle Plugin. Tooling stability in such configuration isn't tested, please report encountered issues to https://kotl.in/issue
> The dependency com.squareup.sqldelight:coroutines-extensions:1.4.4 was published in the legacy mode. Support for such dependencies will be removed in the future. See https://kotl.in/0b5kn8 for details.
> :shared:transformNativeMainCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde
> :shared:transformAppleMainCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde
> :shared:transformIosMainCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde
> :shared:transformNativeTestCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde
> :shared:transformAppleTestCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde
> :shared:transformIosTestCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde
> :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.PropertyEvaluationException: Error while evaluating property 'chooseVisibleSourceSetsProjection' of task ':shared:transformNativeMainCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Artifacts of dependency org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.0.1 is built by old Kotlin Gradle Plugin and can't be consumed in this way
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.PropertyEvaluationException: Error while evaluating property 'chooseVisibleSourceSetsProjection' of task ':shared:transformAppleMainCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Artifacts of dependency org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.0.1 is built by old Kotlin Gradle Plugin and can't be consumed in this way
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.PropertyEvaluationException: Error while evaluating property 'chooseVisibleSourceSetsProjection' of task ':shared:transformIosMainCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Artifacts of dependency org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.0.1 is built by old Kotlin Gradle Plugin and can't be consumed in this way
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.PropertyEvaluationException: Error while evaluating property 'chooseVisibleSourceSetsProjection' of task ':shared:transformNativeTestCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Artifacts of dependency org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.0.1 is built by old Kotlin Gradle Plugin and can't be consumed in this way
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.PropertyEvaluationException: Error while evaluating property 'chooseVisibleSourceSetsProjection' of task ':shared:transformAppleTestCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Artifacts of dependency org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.0.1 is built by old Kotlin Gradle Plugin and can't be consumed in this way
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.PropertyEvaluationException: Error while evaluating property 'chooseVisibleSourceSetsProjection' of task ':shared:transformIosTestCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Artifacts of dependency org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.0.1 is built by old Kotlin Gradle Plugin and can't be consumed in this way
> The dependency org.kodein.di:kodein-di:7.1.0 was published in the legacy mode. Support for such dependencies will be removed in the future. See https://kotl.in/0b5kn8 for details.
> Artifacts of dependency org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.0.1 is built by old Kotlin Gradle Plugin and can't be consumed in this way

Comment: Текст ошибки говорит сам за себя -- `Android Gradle Plugin compatibility issue: The applied Android Gradle Plugin version (8.3.0-alpha11) is higher than the maximum known to the Kotlin Gradle Plugin.` Последний стабильный AGP 8.1.2

Comment: Спасибо большое